# compiling problem ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color ` white'

Tags: color

i can't recognize where is the problem
i keep getting this error ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color ` white'.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%pour la mise en page des tableaux
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{datetime}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
  \usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\usepackage[breakable, skins]{tcolorbox}


% Boîte type générique
\newtcolorbox{boitetype}[4][]{enhanced, breakable, before
upper = {\parindent17.6pt}, beforeafter skip =
\baselineskip, colframe = #3, colback = #4, boxrule = 2pt,
arc = 4mm, fonttitle = \bfseries, title = {#2}, coltitle
= black, #1}



\newenvironment{boite}[3][]{\begin{boitetype}[#1]{#2}{#3}{
white}}{\end{boitetype}}




\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 
\begin{center} 
\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{fms.jpg} \\[1.5cm]

\textsc{\LARGE{}Université de médecine ibn el jazzar sousse} \\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\Large{}premier cycle des études médicales} \\[0.5cm] 
\textsc{\large{}Médecine préventive et communautaire} \\[0.5cm] 
\HRule \\[0.6cm]
{\huge\bfseries{}Le cancer du col de l'utérus} \\[0.25cm]
\HRule \\[1.5cm]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\author{Nom1 \and Nom2 \and Nom3}
\Large\textit{Auteurs :} \\
 Lamia \textsc{azizi}\
 
  Imen \textsc{mhmadi}\
 
 Linda \textsc{lansari}\
 
 Charbel \textsc{saliba}\
 
 Maram \textsc{melliti}\

 Marwa \textsc{hazmiri}\

Abdelaziz \textsc{karaa}
 
Mohamed \textsc{abdallahi}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\Large\textit{Superviseur :} \\

Dr.Olfa \textsc{ezzi} 
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage} \\[2cm]
\monthyeardate\large\today \\[2cm] 

\end{center}
\vfill 

\end{titlepage}

\clearpage\setcounter{page}{2}
\begin{huge}
 \begin{center}
 \section*{Introduction}
 \end{center}
\end{huge}



\lettrine[lines=3]{c'}{est} un cancer invasif qui de se développe à partir de l'épithélium malpighien du col de l'utérus qui reprèsente un problème de santé publique dans le monde et surtout les pays en voie de développement.\\
Il est le 4ème cancer le plus fréquent qu monde avec $570000$ cas dans le monde et il a causé plus de $311000$ décès\cite{who}.\\
Son coût individuel est en moyenne $3200$ DT et le coût à l'échelle nationale s'élève à $877680$ DT \cite{2}.\\
En tunisie, ce cancer est classé comme le 2ème cancer le plus répandu \cite{t}.\\
Au cours des dernières années,il a été démontré que le papillomavirus humain HPV est impliqué dans la genèse de la majorité des cas du cancer du col, le risque est aussi accru par d'autres facteurs de risque comme les partenaires sexuels multiples.\\
Le seul test de dépistage pour ce cancer est le frottis cervical (FC).
Parmi les mesures préventives on peut citer le port du préservatif et la vaccination contre le HPV et cela résume le rôle du médecin de famille.




\hypersetup{hidelinks}
    \tableofcontents
    
    
    
    \part{Epidémiologie descriptive}
    \chapter*{Fréquence}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Fréquence}
    \begin{enumerate}
    
    \item \begin{large}
\underline{Dans le monde:}
\end{large}\\
    
    
    
Les dernières données épidémiologiques montrent que le cancer du col de l'utérus est le 4ème cancer le plus courant chez la femme avec une incidence de $570000$ nouveaux cas en 2018 \cite{1}.


Une prévalence estimée de $3955000$ femmes présentant un cancer du col de l'utérus dans le monde \cite{18}


On note que les pays à faible ou moyen revenu sont les plus touchés par cette mortalité.

En europe, près de $65000$ femmes sont touchées par le cancer du col de l'utérus, et environ $25000$ cas sont recensés chaque année.
On dénombre chaque année environ $30000$ nouveaux cas de lésions précancéreuses, et on estime que ce cancer a touché de l'ordre de $2800$ femmes en France en 2015.\\


\item \begin{large}
\underline{En Tunisie:}
\end{large}\\


En Tunisie, l'incidence du cancer du col utérin dans la région du nord, qui couvre autour de $50 \%$ de la population tunisienne, a été estimée à $5.4/100000$ femmes $-$soit un peu au dessous de la moyenne mondiale$-$ au cours de la période $1999-2003$ et elle variait selon l'âge.







    
    
    \end{enumerate}

    
    \begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.55
\linewidth]{frequence.png}
\caption{Taux d'incidence du cancer du col utérin (1999-2003)}
\end{figure}
    
   
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    \chapter*{Mortalité}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Mortalité}
     \begin{enumerate}
    
    \item \begin{large}
\underline{Dans le monde:}
\end{large}\\
    
    Le cancer du col de l'utérus figure parmi les 4 premiers cancer en terme de mortalité avec les cancers du sein et des poumons pour la population féminine mondiale.
    
    On peut déduire avec un simple calcul que : 
     
    $$Taux\  de\  létalité=\frac{Nombre\  de\  morts\  liées}{Nombre\  de\ cas}=\frac{311000}{39950000}=0.073=7.3\%$$
    
    Cela reprèsente un nombre très important qui est plus accentué dans le pays peu développés comme le montre la figure ci-dessous:
       \begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.75
\linewidth]{mortalite.png}
\caption{Taux de mortalité du cancer du col utérin en $2020$}
\end{figure}


   \item \begin{large}
\underline{En Tunisie:}
\end{large}\\


Selon l'OMS, la Tunisie a enregistré $199$ morts à cause de ce cancer en 2020 seulement contre $100$ en 2012\cite{maroc dirasa}.
Il figure également dans les 3 premiers cancers en matière de mortalité:
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.6
\linewidth]{tndc.png}
\caption{Taux de mortalité des cancers en Tunisie}
\end{figure}


    
    
    \end{enumerate}
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
      
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    \chapter*{Coût}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Coût}
$\bullet$ Pour le coût individuel, il variait de $777$ à $7458$ DT ($431$ à $4143$ euro)selon le stade FIGO avec une moyenne de $3180\pm1390$ DT ($1766\pm772$ euro).\\


$\bullet$ Le coût à l'échelle nationale a été estimé en $2003$ à $877,680$ DT ($486847$ euro).Même si le coût du traitement du cancer du col n'est pas très excessif en Tunisie, il n'en reste pas moins que le meilleur moyen d'améliorer la survie est le dépistage organisé.\\

$\bullet$ Il y aussi le coût indirect qui n'a pas été estimé en Tunisie mais on peut citer l'exemple du Brézil où ce coût représentait la moitié du coût total qui est égal à $1,321,683,034\$$\cite{brezil}.\\

$\bullet$ Pour le coût de la prévention, le frottis cervical réalisé dans le laboratoire d'analyses coûte environ $16$ DT.





    
    
    
    
    \part{Epidémiologie analytique}
    \chapter*{Facteurs biologiques}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Facteurs biologiques}
  $\bullet$ L'apparition du cancer du col de l'utérus est liée dans $99\%$ des cas au HPV.On estime que $80\%$ des femmes sont infectées par ce virus au cours de leur vie.\\
  % Boîte type générique


\begin{boite}{Un premier exemple}{orange}
C'est pratique, n'est-ce pas ?
\end{boite}
\begin{boite}[colback = violet!50, coltitle = white]{Un deuxiè
me exemple}{violet}
Apportons quelques petits changements, juste pour cette fois.
\end{boite}
\begin{boite}{Un troisième exemple}{cyan}
Retour sur un cas normal d'utilisation.
\end{boite}


  
 
  

  Le HPV est un virus qui se transmet par contact sexuel (pénétration,contact buccogénital,caresse génitale..), c'est un virus à ADN nu qui est très avancé et stable.Il est strictement humain et il conserve son pouvoir infectieux dans le milieu extérieur.Puisqu'il est strictement épithéliotropes.On distingue ceux à troppisme cutané et ceux à tropisme muqueux.\\
  
  $\bullet$ Ce virus a été prouvé oncogène dans la thèse du Dr. Harald Zur Hausen honoré par le prix Nobel en $2008$ et qui affirme que seule l'infection persistante peut progresser vers le cancer.\\
  
   $\bullet$ Le risque est augmenté aussi par l'immundéficience causée par une transplantation ou par le HIV.
   
  
  
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
        

    \chapter*{Facteurs environnementaux}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Facteurs environnementaux}
         $\bullet$ Tout facteur suspectible de favoriser l'infection par le HPV est considéré comme un facteur indirect induisant au cancer du col utérin et on peut citer :
         \begin{itemize}
         \item Début de la sexualité précoce.
         \item Avoir des partenaires sexuels multiples.
         \item La non protection pendant les rapports.\\
         \end{itemize}
         
         
          $\bullet$ Le tabagisme et l'alcoolisme sont aussi liés à l'augmentation du risque.
          
          $\bullet$ 
        
        
        
        
        
        
        

    \chapter*{Facteurs liés aux système de soin}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Facteurs liés aux système de soin}
        
         $\bullet$ Le manque de compagne gratuites et en masse de dépistage pour le HPV est 

    \chapter*{Facteurs comportementaux}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Facteurs comportementaux}

    
    
    
    
    
    \part{Prévention}
    \chapter*{Introduction}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

    \chapter*{Prévention primaire}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Prévention primaire}

    \chapter*{Prévention secondaire}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Prévention secondaire}

    \chapter*{Prévention tertiaire}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Prévention tertiaire}

    
    
    
    \part*{Conclusion}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Conclusion}










































\end{document}
```

Comment: as the error message shows you have `<space>white` which is not a defined color. from here:`\newenvironment{boite}[3][]{\begin{boitetype}[#1]{#2}{#3}{
white}}{\end{boitetype}}`

Comment: what do i have to do to make it work?  i just copied the code from internet

Comment: just delete the space (newline) before `white` in your file.

Comment: that was so simple....thank youuuuu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
\begin{boitetype}[#1]{#2}{#3}{
  white}
```

which generates the error as  `white` isn't a defined color name. Simply delete the white space (newline)

```
\begin{boitetype}[#1]{#2}{#3}{white}
```